# Using drupal_add_css to dynamically add inline CSS based on term reference

Tags: theming

I'm trying to create a CSS class called `.bg-unit-color` which will change depending on the taxonomy reference chosen

I've set up a course category taxonomy and then set up a color field within it using jQuery Colorpicker module.  I've got to the point where I can render the color in my node--example.tpl.php file with the following:

`<?php

$term=taxonomy_term_load($node->field_example_category['und'][0]['tid']);
$category_color=field_view_field('taxonomy_term',$term,'field_example_category_color');
echo render($category_color);
?>`

I've also used the drupal_add_css function in my template.php file, so this works:

`$new_color='black';
drupal_add_css(".bg-unit-color {background-color: $new_color;}", 'inline');`

However I can't marry the two together to create what I'd like to do which is this:

`drupal_add_css(".bg-unit-color {background-color: $category_color;}", 'inline');`

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a little more context on what you tried in the last example? What happened when you tried to do what you really want? Including the entire hook you wrote (or at least all the code for this part and the hook name) in template.php would be helpful.

Comment: If I include all of the following in my template file, I just get the white screen of death. $term=taxonomy_term_load($node->field_example_category['und'][0]['tid']);
$category_color=field_view_field('taxonomy_term',$term,'field_example_category_color'); drupal_add_css(".bg-unit-color {background-color: $new_color;}", 'inline');

Comment: Also, I'm using jQuery Color picker for the color field

Comment: Are you putting the code into a function or just directly into you template.php file?

Comment: @acrosman I was putting it directly into the template.php file. I've since been told I should be putting it into a function like `<?php

function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  
}`  so that's my next step. Although I haven't quite got there yet

Comment: yes you need to put it into a preprocess hook of some kind. What are you trying to attach the class to? The body tag, a specific div, something else?

Comment: @acrosman I'm just going to add the `.bg-unit-color` class to a div in the node--content-type template file.

Answer (score 1):

If using [render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7.x) you should attach the css to that render array.

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($node->field_example_category['und'][0]['tid']);
$category_color = field_view_field('taxonomy_term',$term,'field_example_category_color');
$name = $term->name;
$category_color['#attached']['css'][] = array(
  'data' => ".bg-unit-color {background-color: $name;}", 
  'type' => 'inline',
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mikey. I can't get this to work though. The problem seems to be that the following code `$term = taxonomy_term_load($node->field_example_category['und'][0]['tid']);
$category_color = field_view_field('taxonomy_term',$term,'field_example_category_color');` causes a white screen of death when I put this in my template.php file

Comment: @Rick I got that code directly from your question so I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: I think the issue was that I need to put the code in a function like `<?php

function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  
}` ...wasn't doing that before

Answer (score 0):

To update the classes on a node based on a field value you can use [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x). I would put my CSS into a file, have the file attached to all pages via the theme, and then set a class on the node's wrapping div:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if($vars['node']->type == 'my_content_type') {
    $term=taxonomy_term_load($vars['node']->field_example_category['und'][0]['tid']);
    $category_color=field_view_field('taxonomy_term',$term, 'field_example_category_color');
    $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class($category_color);
  }
}
```

A non-code solution would be to use the [Field Formatter CSS Class module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class).